# Using custom permissions in a formula field

Tags: formula-field, custom-permission

My aim is to create a formula field on user object which validates that a user has been assigned to a particular permission set or not.

Step1:
I created a custom permission called `New_Custom_Permission`

Step2:
I created a new permission set called `New_Custom_Permission_Set` and added the above custom permission to this permission Set.

Step3:
I assigned a user `John` to `New_Custom_Permission_Set`

Step4: I created a formula field of boolean type on user object called "Check Permission" which refers to `$Permision.New_Custom_Permission`

[image]

I expect the value of CheckPermission formula field on John user record as `true` but it is returning `false`. What is wrong with my approach here?

Comment: can you post your formula code

Comment: I added my formula field image. It is just `$Permision.New_Custom_Permission` and return type is `boolean`

Comment: $Permision.New_Custom_Permission will show current logged in user's persmission?

Comment: @SarathGarimella you should post this as answer

Comment: @SarathGarimella oh, so it won't work based on the user record then?

Comment: @SantanuBoral i only know the problem but still figuring out how to achieve the desired result.

Comment: There is no way, in a formula, to determine if an arbitrary user has Permission X. You can only check if the logged in user has permission.

Comment: I will work on the user record if that user logs in and check his record

Comment: normally custom permissions are good to use in validation rules

Answer (score 3):

I just duplicated this. I created the custom permission, assigned to a permission set, and then created a boolean formula field with the syntax:

```
$Permission.Dan_Permission
```

The formula result on the record were false.

I assigned the permission set to myself as $ is current user.

The formula results to true.

So in this use case I think you should adjust your approach to check the current user is not an assigned user such as createdby or owner.

Comment: I tried the above and doesn;t work for me . Getting "field doesn;t exist" error message . IF( $Permission.custom_permission1, "usertype-1",
IF( $Permission.custom_permission2 , "usertype-2","Default"))